# until loop is getting stuck; acting strangely?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I have the loop below and its behavior seems strange to me.

It's part of a BlackJack game and it is asking for the user to input a bet.  If the bet is more than the amount of money the user has then it loops back around.

`c` is equal to 500 here:

```
b = 90000000
until b < c
  puts "You have $" + c.to_s + "."
  puts "How much do you want to bet? "
  b = gets.to_i
  if b < c
    @bet = gets.to_i
  else
    puts "Nice try."
  end
end
```

I set `b` to a high number to ensure that the loop is run at least once. When I start the loop and enter numbers higher than the money I have, it does what it's supposed to, and loops asking for a bet.  But, when I finally enter a valid amount the loop gets stuck.

Then when I set `b` to a low enough number so that it skips over the `until` everything works fine.

Does anyone know why my loop is sticking?

Comment: Reverse the logic of your `until`. Instead use `while b >= c` or a simple `loop` with a `break` that tests your condition. `until` negates the logic, making it harder to read and understand. It's part of Ruby, but seldom used for that reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not 'sticking', it's waiting for IO.

You have a second call to `gets` inside your `if b < c` block.  Your loop is executing the final time, you are entering a value < c, your if block is entered, and your program is waiting for you to read more input.

Change your inner if block to

```
if b < c
  @bet = b
else
  puts "Nice try."
end
```

and you should be ok.